# groovy or java: how can replace '\' with '\\' 'C:\www\web-app\StudyReports\test.bat'

Tags: java, regex, groovy

My eventual goal is to have a string like

```
def newline = 'C:\\www\web-app\StudyReports\\test.bat'
```

but my old line only has one `'\'`.

I tried different ways of using the following:

```
def newline = oldline.replaceAll(/\\/,'//')
```

but that did not compile.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean replace '\' with '/'?

Comment: Look for a correct answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42296082/715269

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you'd use the [`String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), which is NOT regex-based.

You'd write something like:

```
String after = before.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

This doubles up every `\` in `before`.

```
String path = "1\\2\\\\3\\4";
System.out.println(path);
path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\");
System.out.println(path);
```

The output of the above is ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/cT9Ej))

```
1\2\\3\4
1\\2\\\\3\\4
```

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would replace the backslashes with forward slashes:

```
def newline=oldline.replaceAll(/\\+/, '/')
```

Both Java and Windows will accept the forward slash as a file separator, and it's lot easier to work with.

Comment: nice use of + operator to side step problems with trailing /

Comment: @PeterKahn why does `/\\/` not compile?

Comment: I think it's confusion between the \ as character and as escape for the next character, the closing /

Answer (score 2):

To match a single backslash in Java or Groovy, you have to enter it 4 times, because **both the compiler and the regex** engine use the backslash as the escape character. So if you enter `"\\\\"` as a String in Java, the compiler generates the string containing the two characters `\\`, which the regex engine interprets as a match for exactly one backslash `\`.

The replacement string must be **escaped twice** too, so you have to enter 8 backslashes as the replacement string.