# Replace backslashes in a string using Java/Groovy

Tags: java, string, groovy

Trying to get a simple string replace to work using a Groovy script.  Tried various things, including escaping strings in various ways, but can't figure it out.

```
String file ="C:\\Test\\Test1\\Test2\\Test3\\"
String afile = file.toString() println
"original string: " + afile
afile.replace("\\\\", "/")
afile.replaceAll("\\\\", "/") println
"replaced string: " + afile
```

This code results in:

```
original string: C:\Test\Test1\Test2\Test3\
replaced string: C:\Test\Test1\Test2\Test3\
```

### ----------------------------

The answer, as inspired by Sorrow, looks like this:

```
  // first, replace backslashes
  String afile = file.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
  // then, convert backslash to forward slash
  String fixed = afile.replaceAll("//", "/")
```

Comment: Your answer section does not make any sense to me: first of all, `assert file.class == file.toString().class`, so `toString()` is redundant. You then correctly replace all instances of single backslashes with forward slashes, so that `assert afile == 'C:/Test/Test1/Test2/Test3/'` But then you try to replace all instances of two consecutive forward slashes (which do not exist in the string, see previous assert), with a single forward slash? The simple answer to this question is: `String result = file.replaceAll('\\\\', '/')`, nothing more needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`replace` returns a different string. In Java `String`s cannot be modified, so you need to assign the result of replacing to something, and print that out.

```
String other = afile.replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
println "replaced string: " + other
```

Edited: as Neftas pointed in the comment, `\` is a special character in regex and thus have to be escaped twice.

Comment: Your suggestion keyed me into what I was doing wrong.   What I had to do though, is different than your answer.   First, using your method, I had to replace the double-backslashes and THEN I had to convert them to forward slashes in a second replaceAll call.  I couldn't figure out how to do both tasks simultaneously, believe it or not.   The code in your answer above didn't work.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `String.replaceAll` takes a regex pattern as the first argument, and, as others have pointed out, since \ is both an escape character for strings and regular expressions, you would actually need to type \\\\ to get a literal \ to the regex engine. If you run the code as it is now, you will get a `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException`

Comment: @Neftas updated the answer; thank you for pointing it out (and I probably should have tested the code before pasting it here or at least mention in the original answer that I have not tried it - well, lesson learned)

Answer (score 10):

In Groovy you can't even write `\\` - it is "an unsupported escape sequence". So, all answers I see here are incorrect.

If you mean one backslash, you should write `\\\\`. So, changing backslashes to normal slashes will look as:

```
scriptPath = scriptPath.replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
```

If you want to replace pair backslashes, you should double the effort:

```
scriptPath = scriptPath.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "/")
```

*Those lines are successfully used in the Gradle/Groovy script I have intentionally launched just now once more - just to be sure.*

What is even more funny, to show these necessary eight backslashes "\\\\\\\\" in the normal text here on StackOverflow, I have to use sixteen of them! Sorry, I won't show you these sixteen, for I would need 32! And it will never end...

Answer (score 2):

1) afile.replace(...) doesn't modify the string you're calling it on, it just returns a new string.

2) The input strings (String file ="C:\\Test\\Test1\\Test2\Test3\\";), from Java's perspective, only contain single backslashes. The first backslash is the escape character, then the second backslash tells it that you actually want a backslash.

so

```
afile.replace("\\\\", "/");
afile.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

should be...

```
afile = afile.replace("\\", "/");
afile = afile.replaceAll("\\", "/");
```

Comment: This is not true - replaceAll (in contrast to replace) expects a regex pattern and \ is both an escape character for Java string litererals and for regular expressions, which means that "\\\\" is the pattern which matches a single backslash.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with paths, you're better off using the java.io.File object. It will automatically convert the given path to the correct operating-system dependant path.

For example, (on Windows):

```
String path = "C:\\Test\\Test1\\Test2\\Test3\\";

// Prints C:\Test\Test1\Test2\Test3
System.out.println(new File(path).getAbsolutePath());

path = "/Test/Test1/Test2/Test3/";

// Prints C:\Test\Test1\Test2\Test3
System.out.println(new File(path).getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 1):

In Groovy you can use regex in this way as well:

```
afile = afile.replaceAll(/(\\)/, "/")
println("replaced string: "+ afile)
```

Note that (as Sorrow said) replaceAll returns the result, doesn't modify the string. So you need to assign to a var before printing.

Answer (score 0):

String Object is immutable so if you call a method on string object that modifies it. It will always return a new string object(modified). So you need to store the result return by replaceAll() method into a String object.

Answer (score 0):

As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24001617/595305), the best candidate might be the `static` `Matcher` method:

```
Matcher.quoteReplacement( ... )
```

According to my experiments this doubles single backslashes. Despite the method name... and despite the slightly cryptic Javadoc: "Slashes ('\') and dollar signs ('$') will be given no special meaning"