# Using backslashes in Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm using groovy to write a script that replaces UNC server names and a part of the directory structure.  I have the following:

```
def patternToFind = /\\\\([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\\share\\([a-zA-Z]+)/
def patternToReplace = '\\\\\\\\SHARESERVER\\\\share\\\\OPS'
```

This works, but all those \'s are pretty ugly.  I understand in the regex why `\\\\` is used to find `\\`, but what is confusing me is why in the replacement I'm doing I have to use four `\`'s to equal one `\`.

If anyone has a nicer way to do this I would greatly appreciate it.  The goal is to replace

`\\<server>\share\<env>`

with the correct value for `<server>` and `<env>`

Thanks!

EDIT:  I guess I should clarify.  SHARESERVER and OPS are actually variables.  So truly the end result would be something like:

```
def serverName = //some passed in server
def env = //some passed in env

def patternToFind = /\\\\([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\\NAS\\([a-zA-Z]+)/
def patternToReplace = '\\\\\\\\' + serverName + '\\\\share\\\\' + env
```

So the only way I think of doing it is building a string literal to replace the section I'm looking for with.

And I'll be the first to admit that I suck at reg ex, so if you can use them to capture a value in a string and replace just that value with another, I'm all ears.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Was trying to figure out how to escape those characters

Comment: Can't you use the same slashy string format used for patternToFind? `/\\\\SHARESERVER\\share\\OPS/`

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't it work with

```
def patternToReplace = $/\\SHARESERVER\share\OPS/$
```

Comment: Yup it should `assert ($/\\SHARESERVER\share\OPS/$ ==~ /\\\\SHARESERVER\\share\\OPS/)`. Forgot about the `$/` dollar slashy string. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a literal replacement string (as opposed to one that involves `$n` backreferences) with a regular expression in Java then the safest thing to do is use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29):

```
def patternToReplace = Matcher.quoteReplacement(/\\SHARESERVER\shares\OPS/)
```

Comment: Ha... well spotted.  According to my experiments this doubles single backslashes. Despite the method name... and despite the slightly cryptic Javadoc: "Slashes ('\') and dollar signs ('$') will be given no special meaning"