# How to replace string in jenkins pipeline using groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I'm trying to replace a string in jenkins pipeline using groovy script the string is

input : prakash/annam/devops
expected output : prakash/\annam/\devops

I'm using this sed -i 's#/#/\#g' . Unfortunately it is working in shell scripting but not in jenkins pipeline. Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
'prakash/annam/devops'.replaceAll("/", "/\\\\")
```

will do what you want. Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377310/3355860

Answer (score 1):

```
str = str.replaceAll( '/', '/\\' )
```

What you can do with strings in groovy:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html